# Executing cURL command in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

how to execute the following cURL command in JSP,

```
$ curl -d lang=fr -d badge=0 http://www.redissever.com/subscriber/J8lHY4X1XkU
```

it is helpful if u explain with some code.thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Do it in Java. And not in JSP.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to execute any command from a JSP scriptlet.

```
<%
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("..."); 
p.waitFor(); 
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
String line=reader.readLine(); 
while(line!=null) 
{ 
   out.println(line); 
   line=reader.readLine(); 
} 
%>
```

However, I wouldn't execute an external command if you can do it in pure Java, e.g. using `HttpUrlConnection`.

```
<%
URL url = new URL("...");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String line=reader.readLine(); 
while(line!=null) 
{ 
   out.println(line); 
   line=reader.readLine(); 
}
%>
```

For a POST request, you'd need something like this:

```
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes ("lang=fr&badge=0");
wr.flush ();
wr.close ();
```

Comment: i have tried the Runtime.getRuntime().exec(),but it is displaying a blank page